# Converting a string in Datagridview to Decimal

Tags: vb.net

I have a Colum with in a dataGridview with Amount in the format “5 187.00”
I am trying to sum-up the Colum and have the result in a viable  but what happens is , the system only picks the value “5” not “5,187.00” as I expected. So I am thinking the space in between 5 and 1 is the problem.
My question is how do I prevent the space, or convert the entry to decimal.

I have tried using

```
Dim num as String 

Num =  “5 187.00”

Num =num.Replace(“ ”, “”)

Cell value = Num
```

But this no not responding 
Let me know if anyone can help.

Thank you

Comment: DataGridView columns can be typed - if yours needs decimal, maybe the datatype should be Decimal?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

We are not sure what space it is. (can be a tab also)

Use `Regex` class as shown in below example

```
Dim num As String = "5 678.90"
Dim cellValue As Decimal = 0.0

num = Regex.Replace(num, "\s", "")

cellValue = Convert.ToDecimal(num)
```

You have to import

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. i had also just highlighted and copy the space without knowing what was the value and pasting it in this statement and it worked . ie like this  num = num.Replace("copied value", "")